# Why do some Google AdSense hyperlinks use “s-p: go to”?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, adsense

In some Google ads I have found that the hyperlink `href`s look like this

```
href="s-p: Go to XYZ.com"
```

These work, but I cannot see the code that translates the `s-p:` bit into an actual url.

What 'veil of ignorance' am I peering behind, please? I would like to know how the conversion is done. What technology is in use here?

This is an AdSense issue - see the ads that come between the article and the comments on this page:

http://rortybomb.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/foreclosure-fraud-for-dummies-1-the-chains-and-the-stakes/

Comment: Sorry, do you want to see how google converts the "text to hyperlinks"??  I cant understand your question

Comment: Are you talking about AdWords or AdSense (i.e. adverts on Google result pages or on blogs and other sites)? Can you give an example of a search term or page that has such a hyperlink?

Comment: I would like to know how the conversion is done, pls. What technology is in use here? This is an AdSense issue - see the ad's that come between the article and the comments on this page "http://rortybomb.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/foreclosure-fraud-for-dummies-1-the-chains-and-the-stakes/"

Comment: This would be a clever way to get people to click on ads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link given, the question is about links like this:

```
<a href="s-p: Go to XYZ.com"
   onclick="advert_cookie(); window.location='http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/[...]'; return false;">
XYZ.com
</a>
```

To answer the question, no conversion is done: the JavaScript `onclick` handler sets [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to the given URL, so the (invalid) `href` attribute is simply ignored.

Comment: Many thanks - crystal clear - no longer have any excuse for not 'diving into javascript'....

Answer (score 0):

The most probable answer is that this is a Wordpress plugin for adwords that displays the adds in this particular way.

I had never seen it before so dont take my word just yet but I´m looking into it!

Comment: That is 'kinda' what I thought but I was then mystified when I couldn't find that 'string' in the page source.....thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

The link behaviour is generated by Javascript snippets provided by Google, and not the browser itself.  Hence the text is explicitly set by the Google code, and they chose to show that text for some reason unknown to me.

I know of no browsers supporting the s-p protocol as-is.  Custom browser plugins may provided that functionalty, but I haven't heard of any.